# FGLRX frame rate capped at 60FPS?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, fglrx

I've got a really weird thing where I can't seem to get frame rates to exceed 60FPS exactly. It really seems like a cap is being placed on it, it *never* exceeds 60.000 FPS, though I know I could get a lot more out of it:

```
Using GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
279 frames in 5.0 seconds = 55.800 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
295 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.000 FPS
296 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.200 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
298 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.600 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
298 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.600 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.800 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.000 FPS
```

I can drag the window around smoothly and do other stuff at the same time that `fgl_glxgears` is running and the FPS doesn't really show any difference. It really seems that things are being limited somewhere. Is there any way to find out where this limit is being enforced and how to disable it?

Comment: No, the limit is set by your Monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your monitor cannot display more than 60fps, it does not make any sense for the graphics card to go any faster since you won't be seeing it.

It is swapping buffers with the vertical sync signal (to prevent things like window tearing), there might be ways of disabling this behaviour, but really, why would you want to do that since there is no benefit and will make the picture look worse?

Comment: Only temporarily, I'd just like to see what a good high framerate looks like.

Comment: Then you will have to get yourself a monitor that refreshes faster, otherwise all you are going to see is artifacts and tearing as the video data gets out of sync the the display.

You can try using xrandr to increase the refresh rate - if possible. You may have to decrease the resolution to increase the refresh rate (assuming that your screen does support it - not all guaranteed)

Comment: It's fine, I was able to establish using your answer that my card can push ~800FPS. Thanks.